Find all occurrences of a subgraph in a given graph
I'm working with an undirected graph where each edge has a label (it's not a weight, it can be thought of as value from a set of enumeration values)
I want to search for a subgraph in the graph, such that I get all subgraphs in the main graph that are identical to the given subgraph (identical means the edges have the same labels)
'a': [ ('b', 1) ]
this means the node 'a' is connected to node 'b' with edge have the label '1'
having the undirected graph:
{
'a': [ ('b', 1) ],
'b': [ ('a', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 2) ],
'c': [ ('b', 1), ('d', 3), ('f', 3), ('g', 2) ],
'd': [ ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('e', 2), ('g', 1) ],
'e': [ ('d', 2) ],
'f': [ ('c', 3) ],
'g': [ ('c', 2), ('d', 1) ]
}

main graph
and this subgraph
{
'x': [ ('y', 1), ('z', 3) ],
'y': [ ('x', 1), ('z', 2) ],
'z': [ ('x', 3), ('y', 2) ]
}

given subgraph
the output should be:
[

{
'c': [ ('b', 1), ('d', 3) ],
'b': [ ('c', 1), ('d', 2) ],
'd': [ ('c', 3), ('b', 2) ]
},
{
'd': [ ('g', 1), ('c', 3) ],
'g': [ ('d', 1), ('c', 2) ],
'c': [ ('d', 3), ('g', 2) ]
}

]

output
the problem can be solved by making nested for loops where the nesting level = to the number of nodes in the subgraph, but this is not efficient (in this case it's O(n^3).
I want an efficient algorithm to take any graph and subgraph as inputs and return a list of all subgraphs in the main graph that are identical to the subgraph as illustrated in the above example
I tried to write a DFS search algorithm to search for all subgraphs but I don't know if it's even possible with DFS

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem
